# Displaying progressing image until a javascript function has completed executing

Tags: javascript, html

How can i display a progressing image until a JavaScript function has been executed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function create()
{
  //Perform operation
}
</script>
```

Until the function create() has completed execution , I need to display a progressing image.
This function is called on a button click.

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Display the image after the function has been executed?

Comment: If i got you right you can simply put your code for hiding display image as last line of your create function. This will work fine unless you have an asynchronous javascript call like ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
<div id="loader" class="overlay">
     <div class="processMessage">
          <img src="images/Loader.gif" height="40" width="40" />
     </div>
</div>
```

here is the css :

```
 .processMessage {
        position: fixed;
        top: 30%;
        left: 43%;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 13%;
        z-index: 1001;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .overlay {
        background-color: rgba(216, 216, 224, 0.8);
        z-index: 999;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: none;
    }
```

Now you just have to control it using $("#loader").hide() and .show(). If this is an ajax call you can do like this.

```
try {
    $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: BeforeSend,
    complete: Complete,
    error: Error
    });
} catch (e) {
 Error();
}

function BeforeSend() {
 $("#loader").show();
}

function Complete() {
 $("#loader").hide();
}

function Error(xhr, err, exception) {
 alert("Some exception");
 $("#loader").hide();
 console.log(exception);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery library by including this JQuery library by putting this as a source of your script tag

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now you can use the deferred API of JQuery Like this:-

```js
function create() {

    var deferred = $.deferred;
    blockUI(); // In blockui you can create a dialog using jquery ui 

    //Here do any work you want to do in this function

    deferred.resolve();

    //Here call unblockUI() to delete the dialog created first

    return deferred.promise();

}

var xyz = create();
$.when(xyz).done(function(x) {

    //Any work you want to do after create function is done performing

})
```

You can read more about deferred API here 
Visit http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when